# Как обработать правильно ошибку RxJava2

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxjava2, rxandroid

Вот есть такой код

```
private long getEntireElementsCount(Map<?, Integer> iMap)
{
    return Observable.fromCallable(iMap::values)//
                     .onErrorReturnItem(new ArrayList<>())//
                     .flatMapIterable(iValue -> iValue)//
                     .reduce((iPreviousVal, iNextVal) -> iPreviousVal + iNextVal)//
                     .blockingGet();
}
```

Который работает как требуется до тех пор пока не прилетит в аргумент пустой `Map` и я получаю вот такую ошибку

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Как правильно написать эту проверку?

Если что то не написал в вопрос, спрашивайте, допишу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `reduce` вернет Maybe, который будет пустым, и после `blockingGet` это обратится в `null`, который не приведется к примитивному `long`.

Можно просто поменять возвращаемый тип с `long` на `Integer`.

Если всё-таки не нужен null, то можно привести Maybe к Single в конце цепочки, передав дефолтное значение 0:

```
.toSingle(0)
.toBlockingGet()
```

Ещё проще можно обойтись одним вызовом toBlockingGet с дефолтным значением в качестве аргумента:

```
.toBlockingGet(0)
```